# Scrolling a ListView changes everything from White to Black

Tags: android

I have a custom list view and I want the background of the list to be white, so I do something like this which works great.

```
listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listview);
listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

The problem is when you scroll the list the background of all the list items changes to black, which looks horrible.

I tried in my list view setting the background color to white.  When I inflate the view I also tried setting the background color to white:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Both of these fix the problem of the scrolling background color, but now the item doesn't appear to be clickable even though it is.  What I mean by that is the onClick still works fine, but the background doesn't flash to orange to let the user know he clicked it.

How can I have a white background in a list view, that stays white while scrolling, and does the normal list acitvity orange click background?

Thanks!

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The solution is very simple, you also need to set the cache color hint to white: `setCacheColorHint(Color.WHITE)`. You don't need to change the list items' background color.

Comment: That worked perfectly.
        listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.WHITE);

Comment: listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT); or  android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" //Reuse background color

Comment: transparent didn't work, white did

Comment: @max4ever, can you tell your android version? 2.3.3. transparent works well.

Comment: For more details on this issue take a look at this android dev blog post: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html

Comment: in XML define listview  __android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"__

Answer (score 7):

```
ListView lv = getListView();
setCacheColorHint(0);
```

Set the cache color hint to zero.

Answer (score 6):

Solution is very simple, you also need to set the cache color hint to black in xml.

```
android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
```

Answer (score 3):

Android attempts to improve the performance of ListView scrolling by caching layout information. If you have long scrolling lists of data you should also set the the android:cacheColorHint property on the ListView declaration in the Activity’s AXML definition (to the same color value as your custom row layout’s background). Failure to include this hint could result in a ‘flicker’ as the user scrolls through a list with custom row background colors.
So give the same color to the listitem's background and android:cacheColorHint.you can refer below code.

In my Adapter layout I gave as

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ADAPTER_CONTAINER_PRIMARY"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FAFAEE"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:gravity="center">
     .....
```

And in the List view

```
<ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/LIST_GRID_LIST_INSTANCES"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"     
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:divider="@drawable/Gray"
            android:dividerHeight="0.05dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="#FAFAEE"
            android:background="@drawable/round"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `ListView` is drawn atop a more complex background -- say, a bitmap or gradient -- then you may need to disable the scroll cache entirely. I ended up setting `android:scrollingCache="false"` on my `ListView` to resolve this issue.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:scrollingCache