# Scrolling a ListView changes TextView color back to original color

Tags: android, listview, colors, textview

Basicaly, my question is similar to this one:

[Scrolling a ListView changes everything from White to Black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011945/scrolling-a-listview-changes-everything-from-white-to-black)

The only difference is that I'm dealing with a TextView that changes the color upon scrolling (the TextView is inside a ListView).

I looked up if there's a method similar to setCacheColorHint(Color.WHITE) for a TextView - I didn't find it.

Perhaps I should dynamically set the default TextColor? Because currently, it's being set in XML and then changed in code.

How can I handle this?

Code for changing the color to blue:

```
private void highlightSelectedFile(View vw)
{
    TextView fileName = (TextView) vw.findViewById(R.id.file_name);

    //Log.v("color: ", Integer.toString(fileName.getCurrentTextColor()));       

    if(fileName.getCurrentTextColor() == Color.BLACK) {
        fileName.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

    } else {
        fileName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        removeFromSelectedFiles(new File(fileName.getText().toString()));
    }
}
```

These TextView's go back to BLACK after I scroll the ListView they're inside in:

```
    ListView lv = (ListView) ac.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Comment: Post your code. That will help some of them to post an answer. Always try to post some code so that others can understand you question more clearly. And it will be a proof to let others you have tried some thing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter you might be using a data item that applies data to your views in `Adapter`. When you scroll, your `View`s are recycled and your `getView()` is called with a different `View` object. Your problem can easily be fixed. Just add one more `int color;` variable in you data item and use it like this.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // efficient stuff here

    // after applying your data
    fileName.setTextColor(data.color);
}
```

also change this method:

```
private void highlightSelectedFile(DataItem data) { 
    if(data.color == Color.BLACK) {
        data.color = Color.BLUE; 
    } else {
        data.color = Color.BLACK;
        removeFromSelectedFiles(new File(fileName.getText().toString()));
    }
   // to update ListView
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: It didn't solve my problem - I tried it. Like I said, the problem is that TextViews change the color back to black, not the ListView itself.

Comment: Ok I got your problem, updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Only put this statement in your list in XML file. android:scrollingCache="false"
It will solve your problem.

Comment: Not working - I'm guessing it has to do with the way TextView renders during scrolling inside a ListView.